# Adjustment of grid in HTML

Tags: html, visual-sourcesafe

How can I adjust HTML grid and how to use row-column-span in HTML?

I tried reading some books for the solution but when I tried the same as mentioned in the book in my HTML website it didn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. What kind of adjustment are you looking for and what have you already tried? Also please supply some code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `grid-template-row` and `grid-template-column` or `grid-template`, or simply you can use inline style to adjust the size of the grid.